# Custom attribute creation in magento 2

Tags: magento2.2.2, custom-attributes

While creating custom attribute in magento 2, what is the use of below

**'backend' => '',
  'frontend' => ''
  'class' => ''
  'source' => ''**

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute(
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
                'sample_attribute',
                [
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'backend' => '',// What is the use of this
                    'frontend' => '',//What is the use of this
                    'label' => 'Sample Atrribute',
                    'input' => 'text',
                    'class' => '',// What is the use of this
                    'source' => '',// What is the use of this
                    'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                    'visible' => true,
                    'required' => true,
                    'user_defined' => false,
                    'default' => '',
                    'searchable' => false,
                    'filterable' => false,
                    'comparable' => false,
                    'visible_on_front' => false,
                    'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                    'unique' => false,
                    'apply_to' => ''
                ]
            );
```

Answer (score 1):

use of source, frontend and backend are given below

**source/frontend/backend**: Special classes associated with the attribute:

**source model:** provides a list of options.

**frontend:** defines how it should be rendered on the frontend

**backend:** allows you to perform certain actions when an attribute is loaded or saved.

you can get more details from this Magento DevDocs https://devdocs.magento.com/videos/fundamentals/add-new-product-attribute/